# How to initialize a QT thread in python

Tags: python, qt, multithreading, pyqt

As per examples seen online, I've created a `Worker` thread.  I'm looking for a thread to run my GUI while one thread executes my code.  `Worker` thread is defined as:

```
class Worker(QThread):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        self.exiting = False
        self.size = QSize(0, 0)

    def __del__(self):
        self.exiting = True
        self.wait()
```

pretty simple.  Within my `Window` class, I have this line in the `__init__` function: `self.thread = Worker()`.  However, I never do anything with that self.thread afterwards.  What am I supposed to be doing with it?  This does not seem to be laid out as nicely as other threading mechanisms..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine you're looking at the example [here](http://diotavelli.net/PyQtWiki/Threading,_Signals_and_Slots)? But that example *does* "do something with that thread afterwards" -- it hooks up methods to respond to the signals the thread sends when it starts and finishes, in the `class Worker` it defines a `run` method that draws random stars , etc etc.  Not sure what you think is wrong with how this is "laid out"?

Comment: Actually that was not the example I'd been pointed to.  Interesting.  I don't understand, however, how in that example both the worker thread and the window thread seem to be drawing to the screen, since I imagine you need to be within the Window class to draw on the Window?

Comment: The painting on the windows' pixmap is done in the window's method `addImage`, which is connected to a signal emitted by the worker when a star is ready. Do read the text as well as the code in the example I point to, I think it does explain things pretty well!

Comment: Reading it through a few times is making a bit more sense.. Is it possible to emit a signal with something other than a QT type?  Could I emit a signal from my thread that sends back two lists of QT objects?